# Memory leaks in Magento on Centos with Nginx & PHP-FPM + Redis

Tags: php, nginx, magento-1.9

Hi we are recently getting the following errors from our cron job....

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/ourdomainname.co.uk/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291
```

So for testing purposes we Increased the memory limit from 1024mb to 1536mb and it leaked out of this too.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 80 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/ourdomainname.co.uk/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291
and
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612712 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 56 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/ourdomainname.co.uk/htdocs/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 270
 and
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 120 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/ourdomainname.co.uk/htdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php on line 562
```

We are also experiencing many php-fpm segfaults exiting on signal 11...

```
    Nov 22 07:46:28 kernel: php-fpm[70200]: segfault at 7fffcf716ff0 ip 00000000005e5285 sp 00007fffcf716fd0 error 6 in php-fpm[400000+351000]
```

Can anyone shed any light on these issues?

We are using:

```
Mangento 1.9.3.1 

CentOS release 6.8 (Final) 

nginx.x86_64 1.8.1-1.el6.ngx @nginx

php55u.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-cli.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-common.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-devel.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-fpm.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-gd.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-ldap.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-mbstring.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-mcrypt.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-mysqlnd.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-odbc.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-opcache.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-pdo.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-pear.noarch 1:1.10.1-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 1.3.9-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64 1.3.9-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-pgsql.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-process.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-soap.x86_64 5.5.31-1.ius.centos6 @ius
php55u-xml.x86_64

redis.x86_64 3.2.1-2.el6.remi @remi
```

Yours hopfully